# How do you set a control anchor with FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, anchor, firemonkey

FireMonkey controls do not appear to have anchor properties as do VCL controls. How do I make FireMonkey controls automatically adjust when the form resizes?

Comment: Why am I asking and answering my own questions? See https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=392768&tstart=0#392768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi XE **3** provides the `anchors` with FireMonkey².

Answer (score 5):

The anchors property in VCL has apparently been replaced by Margins and Padding (due to performance considerations) and I found some documentation at the [XE2 wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Application_Design).  Set the margins on the bottom panel to create a smaller space in which the buttons will live, make sure you set the align to alRight.

For example the gap between the right edge of the form and the right most button has a margin of 15. The top and bottom margins were 12. Padding is the opposite to a margin, the padding puts space outside the control. For the right most button I added a padding of 20 to the left side, this will be the space between the two buttons. For the second button all we need to do is set the align property to alRight, no need to adjust the padding or margins.

Comment: Original answer by Herbert Sauro at https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=386900&tstart=0#386900

Answer (score 2):

Custom anchoring can be done by stacking some TLayer. For example, something like 'align a button to the left top corner' can only be achieved by aligning a layer to the left and then by aligning a button (in the layer) to the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LiveBindings and expressions to change the properties of a control based on the parent control. Otherwise, use Margins and Padding (like HTML/CSS).

Answer (score 0):

```
Button1.Anchors := [TAnchorKind.akTop, TAnchorKind.akRight];
```